# Azure - 12 hour logging

Tags: azure, logging, azure-web-roles

So I'm trying to familiarise myself with Azure and have started work on a website which is currently being deployed on git commit to Azure. I decided I had to look at logging and so turned on application diagnostics in the Azure portal. I logged via a trace statement in my code and sure enough it writes to a log file.

I noticed that on hover of the info icon at the side of the "application logging (filesystem)" toggle, that it notes it will be turned off after 12 hours. I presumed that meant diagnostic logging will be turned off after 12 hours, but over 20 hours later that seems not to be the case.

Does the 12 hours refer to the retention of file logs post creation or geniunely that logging will (at some point) be switched off?

From the little I've read if I want durable logging I need to consider pushing log files to blob storage or azure tables (possibly writing directly). Are my thoughts on the 12 hour retention to be correct?

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 0):

This 12 hours limit is about application logging into text file(s): if you use an `ILogger` instance to log data (ie. `logger.LogInformation(...)`) then this feature will be disabled after 12 hours.